# Windows gawk search with leading zeros

Tags: awk

Good day.
I am running GNU awk 3.1.6 in a batch file under Windows 7 Pro.  I want to print select records from a tilde delimited CSV file based on a pattern match on column 40.  Column 40 contains numeric data of 1 to 8 digits.  Leading zeros are significant ie. 885 is different from 0885.  The argument to compare to column 40 is supplied on the batch file command line.

I have tried all sorts of combinations of backslashes, quotes, swears, percent, brackets, carets - except for the correct one.

```
awk "BEGIN { FS = ""~""""; OFS = ""~"""" } $40 == %1 { print $1, $30, $40\"\", $39, $15, $19, $53, $4, $21 }" "MyFile.csv" > OutFile.csv
```

However, the above command when searching for 0885 will find both 0885 and 885.  How do I get awk to see the distinction between 885 and 0885 and preserve the leading zero if there?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`==` performs arithmetic comparison if both arguments look like numbers (I'm guessing `%1` here is your Windows batch file parameter?). To force a textual comparison, try using a regex instead.

```
$40 ~ /^%1$/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This does not return any records.  From the batch file output it looks like it is looking for /^0885$/ literally.

Comment: Is that not what you want? Or do you mean it's trying to find caret, zero, eight, eight, five, dollar sign? I fortunately do not have access to Windows so I can't test on your platform, but it works for me. Demo: http://ideone.com/pBEbPq

Comment: Thanks again, tripleee.  I tried your example under WSL CentOS, and NetBSD 7.  There was no output from either.  There are no matches under Windows cmd when I substituted \$40 ~ /^%1\$./.

Comment: Because `%1` does not make sense on WSL, CentOS, or NetBSD; and you probably should not escape the dollar signs on Windows. My IdeOne demo shows you how to do this in Bash. Maybe you need to change the quoting to expose the `%1` on Windows; this is far outside of my competence.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.  Under Windows I used %1.  Under WSL CentOS, NetBSD, and now Ubuntu I used your script without modification.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong; IdeOne runs the code and displays the result.

Comment: I still don't have it right.  I downloaded your script and ran it.  This is the result:
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dchapman dchapman 369 Aug 21 02:40 ideone_pBEbPq.sh
[dchapman@T430s]/mnt/c/Users/dchap/Documents% ./ideone_pBEbPq.sh 885
*** experiment 885 ***
        this contains number 885 and should match on that
*** experiment 0885 ***
        this contains string 0885 and should only match that
[dchapman@T430s]/mnt/c/Users/dchap/Documents%

As you can see, it returned both results.  
Thanks ever so much for your time.

Comment: It returned only 855 when it ran this experiment, and only 0855 in that experiment. The script itself does not accept arguments; it simply runs the experiment twice with thee diffenet arguments. So the first ex´eriment shows the output when you run the function with the parameter 855, and the output demonstrates that only that line is indeed matched in that particular experiment.

Comment: Oh.  Well in that case it works fine under NetBSD and the few Linux distros I tried.  Not with Windows, however.  The search continues..
Thanks again for your time.

Comment: This works:
awk -F~ "$40 ~ "/[" "]+^%1$"/ { gsub(/ /, \"\", $40); gsub(/ /, \"\", $39); print $1,\"~\",$30,\"~\",$40,\"~\",$39,\"~\",$15,\"~\",$19,\"~\",$53,\"~\",$4,\"~\",$21 }" MyFile.csv >> OutFile.csv
Although I'm not all that happy with it.  I can't make it work with FS= and OFS=.

Comment: Try just `-F~ "BEGIN { OFS=FS }`... but I really don't understand how the `[" "]` in front of `^` could work, let alone do something useful.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with OFS=.  I had an extra double quote.
Columns $39 and $40 have variable number leading spaces.  My idea with [" "]+ is to look past these spaces for the search target.

Comment: But the regex beginning o# line anchor `^` should only match at the start of the field.